# SQL get max id value from all tables in all databases

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to get the database name, schema name, table name and max id value from all tables in all databases. Using following query I get the DBname, Schema and TableName but cannot figure out how to get the max(id) value also into the table.

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR
SET @getDBName = CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases
CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (
                        DBName VARCHAR(256),
                        SchemaName VARCHAR(256),
                        TableName VARCHAR(256)
                        )
OPEN @getDBName
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            SET @varSQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + ';
            INSERT INTO #TmpTable
            SELECT '''+ @DBName + ''' AS DBName,
            SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
            name AS TableName
            FROM sys.tables'

            EXEC(@varSQL)

            FETCH NEXT FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
        END
CLOSE @getDBName

DEALLOCATE @getDBName
SELECT * FROM #TmpTable
DROP TABLE #TmpTable
```

Comment: are you assuming all tables have the same key field name?

Comment: Yes, id as a field name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
     '@DBName' AS DBName, 
      IDENT_CURRENT(Name) MaxId,
      SCHEMA_NAME(Schema_ID) AS SchemaName,
      name AS TableName
FROM sys.Tables
```